# I've created a file, "sqlKill.shutdown", in ~/lib/systemd/system-shutdown, was this the correct way to stop MSSQL at shutdown?

Tags: 20.04, scripts, xubuntu, shutdown, mssql

My mssql-server service has a bad habit of not being stopped at shutdown. To remedy this, I've navigated to ~/lib/systemd/system-shutdown and created the file sqlKill.shutdown containing exactly the following

```
#!/bin/sh
sudo systemctl stop mssql-server.service
```

Is this a sufficient and safe way to force MSSQL server to stop at shutdown?

Comment: If you shutdown your computer, it should **stop** all running service. Can anyone clarify this ?

Comment: I agree with @Liso. I’ve been running SQL Server on Linux since 16.04 and it consistently shuts down correctly when the system goes down for a reboot. What issue are you seeing when you try to shut down? Is there anything in the log that points to the issue, such as delayed writes, an open transaction, or something else? 

Comment: @matigo When I shut down, I'll get the to splash screen and the shutdown will never finish. Pressing an arrow key shows that I'm waiting on mssql-server to stop, but it never does stop. There shouldn't be anything of relevant in the server logs, but if you can tell me where to look, then I will get back to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One week later. I've not had any issues since doing this, so I guess it was safe?